# Libboost package installion error on Raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: pi-3, software-installation, apt, packages

Command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.50-all-dev
```

Result:

```
Error: Could not find any package by globe and regex libboost1.50-all-dev
Error: Unable to locate package libboost1.50-all-dev
```

Comment: It's strange, I can see the `libboost1.50-all-dev` package in the raspbian repo. Can you install any other packages?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev libboost1.50-x is probably Jessie. Looking with `apt policy` I can only see 1.58 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Raspbian version because libboost1.50 is only available in Rapsbian Jessie.

You can check YOUR version with: lsb_release -a

Check the available libboost versions with: apt-cache search libboost

then install the latest version with: sudo apt-get install libboost1.62-*

Comment: Why do you need to add that repo? I thought that was a Ubuntu repo, not Debian/Raspbian.

Comment: @Dirk, You'r completely right that is for Ubuntu. Multitasking is not my favorite, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This package is probably not available for your system (as the other answer already suggests).

To list all packages from `libboost` that **are** available do `sudo apt-cache search libboost`.

Probably, this will show several files and different versions. But there will also be `libboost-all-dev` which should contain all available packages in the **most recent versioning**.